# Terminate applications opened with "subprocess.Popen()"?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to view an image in Eye of Gnome (eog), and then have it automatically close later.
I am not very well versed in subprocess, but so far I have tried:

```
eog = subprocess.Popen('oeg <some file>', shell=True)
# ...Code, Code, Code...
eog.kill()
```

or

```
eog.terminate()
```

Neither work. Any help?

Comment: Post more of your code and how did you checked if the process was killed.

Comment: They both work on my machine?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `shell=True`, example:

```
import subprocess, shlex
command = 'eog <filename'>
eog = subprocess.Popen(shlex(command))
..code..
eog.kill()
```